# Bounded quantifiers don't count in arithmetic hierarchy

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

I was wondering what exactly the statement that "bounded quantifiers don't count" means in arithmetic hierarchy, and why it is the case formally.

For example, consider the set $S$ of programs $p$ that have finite domain. Then $$p\in S\iff (\exists N)(\forall x > N) (\forall z) \neg T(p,x,z)$$ where $T$ is the Kleene $T$-predicate. I suppose formally speaking, the RHS is $(\exists N)(\forall x) (x> N \to (\forall z) \neg T(p,x,z))$. How to show formally that $S$ is $\Sigma_2$? I'm okay with having sequences like $\forall x\forall z$ but I'm not sure how to handle bounded quantifiers.

Similarly, if $T$ is the set of programs with infinite domain, then
$$p\in T\iff (\forall N)(\exists x)(x > N \to \forall z T(p,x,z))$$
in which case it's not clear to me why this is a $\Pi_2$ set.

Another kind of example: the set of programs $R$ that halt on all $x$ less than 100. Here we have
$$p\in R\iff (\forall x)(x < 100 \to \exists z T(p,x,z))$$
Does the fact that "bounded quantifiers don't count" mean that I can completely ignore such quantifiers, and the set above is just  $\Sigma_1$? If so, how to justify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that bounded quantifiers can be "folded in" to the unbounded ones.

Consider for example an expression of the form $\exists x\forall y<x\exists z\varphi(x,y,z)$; let's show that this is $\Sigma_1$.

The idea is to borrow the "flavor" of **Skolemization**. There an expression of the form "$\forall a\exists b$" was reinterpreted as "$\exists F\forall a$" with $F$ a function designed to assign to each $a$ an appropriate $b$. Now in general that makes things **more** complicated, but here something very nice is going on: fixing $x$, a function sending each $y<x$ to some appropriate $z$ is actually a **finite** object and so can be coded by a single natural number.

So we rewrite our original expression as follows:

> There is some pair $x,n$ where $n$ codes a sequence of length $x$ such that for every $y<x$ we have $\varphi(x,y, n[y])$ (where "$n[y]$" denotes the $y$th term of the sequence coded by $n$).

This is straightforwardly $\Sigma_1$ since the "coding/decoding apparatus" is all appropriately simple. The point is that now the bounded quantifier "$\forall y<x$" lives inside all of the unbounded quantifiers.

Comment: This is really hard to process for me... So just using [these equivalences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut6ZC.png) isn't enough? I think they can be used in my 3 examples, but in your example they give $\Sigma_3$... Like $\exists x\forall y( y< x\to \exists z \phi(x,y,z))\iff \exists x\forall y\exists z (y < x \to \phi(x,y,z))$.

Comment: @user634426 Those equivalences are not always enough to give *optimal* complexity calculations; my example is $\Sigma_3$, but it's also $\Sigma_1$, and that's better. You need to play around with the specific details of arithmetic, and coding finite sequences really is the key.

Comment: Hm, so the quoted part in your answer reads "$\exists x\exists n \forall y (y < x\to \phi(x,y,n[y] )$" .There's one quantifier alternation followed by a computable property, but it's still considered $\Sigma_1$?

Comment: As for the coding idea, I think I kind of got it: if say, for $y=1,2,3,4$ there exist $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$, then there is a sequence $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ that can be coded by a number $n$, and then the second existential quantifier from my first comment can be moved past the bounded universal quantifier.

Comment: @user634426 Remember that the hierarchy doesn't really count quantifier alternations, it counts quantifier alternations **after a bounded quantifier matrix** (that is, a $\Delta^0_0$ formula). "$\forall y(y<x\rightarrow ...)$" is exactly what "$\forall y<x(...)$" is short for, so it doesn't count.

Comment: Ok, in other words, I guess, $\forall y < x (...) $ is a "maximal" computable property in this case, so there's 0 alternations. Then, for example, the set of programs halting on all $x < 100$ and the set of programs with cofinite domain are also $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: @user634426 I don't know what you mean by "maximal" computable property, so I can't address that. As to your examples, the first is correct - for any $n$ the set of programs halting on all $x<n$ is c.e. - but your second is not (it's in fact $\Sigma_2$-complete).

Comment: Let $S$ be the set of programs $x$ with cofinite domain $W_x$. I thought $x\in S$ could be represented as $\exists N \forall y > N (y\in W_x)$ or $\exists N\forall y > N \exists z T(x,y,z)$ or $\exists N \exists M \forall y < N T(x,y,M[y])$.

Comment: "$\forall y>N$" is not a bounded quantifier! "Bounded quantifier" means bounded *above.*

Comment: Oops, I went from $\forall y > N$ to $\forall y < N$... The coding you described doesn't work with $\forall y > N$, so my representation is wrong.

Comment: But then how do you see that it's $\Sigma_2$? I can only see that it's $\Sigma_3$: $x\in S\iff \exists N\forall y\exists z(y > N \to T(x,y,z))$.

Comment: @user634426 Oh, that's because I made a typo: "$2$" should indeed by "$3$." It's $\Sigma^0_3$-complete. (They're close together on the keyboard, 's not *my* fault! :P)